# why some people separate live streaming protocol at input and output?

Tags: android, streaming, protocols

for example, some people implement `RTMP` protocol to input to the server, and then implement `HLS` protocol to output.

in my opinion, anyway, at the server, media files that encoded `RTMP` form must be converted to `HLS` form. so why do they do this?

isn't more efficient to use `HLS protocol` at the input?

Answer (score 0):

RTMP protocol is much better fit for real-time video+audio transmission than HLS. HLS is chunk-based protocol which means it has latency and a significant container overhead. RTMP (just like RTSP, MPEGTS or SRT) is optimized for real-time delivery so it will preferably be used for live input.